# Id ceramic disc capacitor

Tags: component-selection, electricity

The mither in-law asked me if I could fix the OLD electric moulinex beater...
Once open I saw that both CDC's connecting the brushes are broken. I am having trouble identifying them, could you help? I'm not in anyway an electronics specialist.
She'd be better off buying a new one but I like a challenge...

Reference numbers:

1n5m 250v 
GA 565-1
HSF

[image: old CDC]

[image: in place]

Can I replace this with a modern equivalent?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think they are just there for noise suppression. It works fine without them so I could probably leave them off.

Comment: If it works fine without them, then I guess you must have fixed the real problem. Just out of curiosity, what was the real problem? Worn-out brushes?

Comment: Ha ! Nothing really, the beaters didn't stay in the holes.. They are captured by  plastic bushings, kinda, just heated the plastic and made the passage narrower. Now I've opened it tho the live wire has broken from its solder so,...

Answer (score 3):

That is a 1.5nanofarad capacitor rated for 250 volts AC.  It is also a Y rated part.  The Y rating is a safety feature.

When you replace it, make sure to get a part that meets (or exceeds) the safety rating and the voltage rating.  Any Y rated part should meet the safety and voltage ratings.

The actual value is not as important.  It is for noise suppresion, as you suspected.  It won't matter if you get a 2nF part, or a 1nF, or the given 1.5nF.  Too small and it won't suppress noise effectively.  Too large and it will pass too much current and may cause problems.  Stay close to one or two nF.

Comment: Oh, if we could only apply noise suppression to mither-in-laws so easily.

Comment: Why are there no smileys when u need one.

Comment: You probably know this but the cap may be listed as 1500pF. Also don't take the safety aspect too lightly (assuming you don't intend on offing the MIL) Y caps are spec'd because it can cause a shock if they fail and kitchens are bad places for shocks because of the grounded sink etc. Modern ones usually have GFI/RCD outlets but there are many without.

Comment: Thanks to all for your help, have a lovely  end of year.